# Schedule to dump sharepoint list to the local drive

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, sharepoint-2013

is there a way to set up an auto schedule to dump the SharePoint list to certain folder ?
any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks 
Ian

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions as described in the article - [Extracting and Loading SharePoint Data in SQL Server Integration Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh368261.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Once you set up your package, it's just a matter of scheduling it via SQL Server Agent